# GCE Docker container process (user)owner is not root

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, docker-swarm

I'm running docker airflow in GCE using docker swarm.
The strange thing is that even though I deployed my airflow cluster with root user, the owner of the airflow process is not root, but some random user in the node.
[image]

When I run docker in my local machine, the process is started with root.
[image]
Is there some kind of rules for choosing a user on GCE??
Does anyone have any clue why this is happeneing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same container image on both systems?

I don't know which image you are using but I had a short look at the `puckel/docker-airflow` image and this one drops the privileges of the container to a regular user named `airflow`.

You can prevent this by removing the `USER airflow` line in the `Dockerfile` or you could specify a specific UID/GID by modifying the `useradd` command in the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Yes I was using the same image in both GCE and my local machine. The process inside the container is started with airflow user alright. I was talking about the host's process. I can see my airflow process which is in the container, from host. The image that I posted is listing airflow processes from the host, not in the container.